# Cannot add into an already initialized array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', saveItem);
function saveItem(e){
var items= document.getElementById('items').value;
var date= document.getElementById('date').value;
var price= document.getElementById('price').value;
var expense= {
    items: items,
    date: date,
    price: price
}


if(localStorage.getItem('bill')==null){
var bill=[];
 bill.push(expense);
 localStorage.setItem('bill', JSON.stringify(expense));


} else{

var bill = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bill'));

bill.push(expense);
localStorage.setItem('bill', JSON.stringify(expense));
console.log(bill);

}
e.preventDefault();
}
```

there is no error if

```
if(localStorage.getItem('bill')==null)
```

but there comes error at else as

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
  at HTMLFormElement.saveItem
```

the data is stored when the local storage is empty but cannot add data if it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expense is a object, you need to save the bill inside the local storage.

```
if(localStorage.getItem('bill')==null){
 var bill=[];
 bill.push(expense);
 localStorage.setItem('bill', JSON.stringify(bill));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check what is the result of `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bill'));`? Is its a valid array?